# Accessing WCF REST operation using WebChannelFactory when the operation has UriTemplate specified

Tags: wcf, rest, uritemplate, webchannelfactory

I have a WCF Rest service as per the code snippet below

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
     [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/SaveList/Foos/",Method="POST")]
        bool SaveList(List<Foo> myFoos);

}
```

The service is a self hosted service and exposes a an endpoint with webHttpBinding. I have a client console application which has the following code snippet:

```
public void Send()
{
   var myObj = new Foo{Id=1, Name="Test"};
   using (WebChannelFactory<OurService.Services.IOurService> cf = new WebChannelFactory<IOurService>("WebHttpBinding_IService"))
   {
       IUtranetService channel = cf.CreateChannel();
       using (new OperationContextScope(channel as IContextChannel))
       {
           var status = channel.SaveList(new[] { myObj });

        }

    }

}
```

The client code throws an exception as follows:
There was no endpoint listening at "http://localhost:1133/Service/SaveList" that could accept the message.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. If I remove the UriTemplate from the service contract, the client returns back the right response.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Ruchitra

Comment: you dont need method=post - webinvoke is already a post

Comment: But removing method=post will not solve the problem. Is there anything wrong that I am doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URI template is incorrect. You need to change it to this:

```
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/SaveList/Foos/SaveList",Method="POST")]
```

It does not automatically append your method name.

Also FYI as per the comment I left, you dont need Method="Post"

Comment: That did not solve the problem either, I am still getting the same exception :-(

Comment: and your Foo Object is marked up [DataContract] etc - or at the very least serializable, right?

Comment: apologies again - should just be UriTemplate ="/SaveList"

Comment: Yes my Foo object is marked with DataContract attribute. In that case it will be the same as not having UriTemplate. But I wanted to provide a nested Uri using UriTemplate. Is that possible?

Comment: Of course - but you need to change the url that you're calling.

Comment: I am using WCFClient to call the operation. I have generated the client by adding service reference in visual studio. I am calling the "SaveList"method on my proxy object. How can I change the Url that I am calling?

Comment: I mean with your client application, you'll have set an address under here: "WebHttpBinding_IService" in your bindings. The address will be blank or "http://localhost:1133/Service/" - something liek that... you need to make sure that the nesting of this (minus the SaveList) matches your UriTemplate (which includes uritemplate) so that your service exists where you expect.

Comment: @Chris, Whether I need to include method name in URI Template or not?